# get single primary key value from datagridview in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to get the primary key value, or whatever key I set, from the selected row in a datagridview with out having to create a hidden column. 
I want the functionality of gridview in asp.net having the DataKeyNames property

Comment: Is your `dataGridView.DataSource` a `DataTable` or you fill your `DataGridView` in another way (e.g. programmatically)?

Comment: With datatable using DataSource

Comment: OK, so are your rows' unique keys in the `DataTable` or not ? I suppose not, otherwise you will fall into "hidden column" problem. Then, if my supposition is correct, I think my answer is good (and the fact you've chosen it reinforces my belief) otherwise let me know, and I'll try to expand my answer ;)

Comment: You have created me a question. Is Tag property fills automatically if I have the unique key in the DataTable? Because I do have it. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed your comment only now... (use @username to notify your comment to someone) `Tag` is null by default, you can use it for whatever you want, but you need to set it manually...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on how you fill the grid, but you could use the `Tag` property of the `DataGridViewRow` to hold your row key.

`Tag` property can hold any object so you can set it to whatever you desire...